# how to correctly group/sort a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help understanding some "next level" mysql/php commands, beyond just simple query statements and looping through arrays.

I have a table that contains publications written by various faculty members. They're all stored together, and there's a faculty_id column that tells me which publication belongs to which faculty member. On a "Bio" web page I want to retrieve these publications...no problem right? The issue I'm having is how to display them: grouped by the 'year' column with the year as a heading. So, for example, the output would look like this:

2010

- publication 1
- publication 2

2009

- publication 1
- publication 2

2007 // assuming there was no pub in 2008

- publication 1
- ...etc.

Here's where I started, what else can I do to make this more efficient? Or is there a way to create a multi-dimensional array from this query below using PHP?

```
"SELECT bibliography,year,link,position FROM faculty_pubs WHERE faculty_id='$faculty_id' AND status=1 ORDER BY year DESC, position ASC"
```

Comment: I should mention there's a primary key in the table called "id" but it isn't used anywhere so I didn't bother including it in the query. and for anybody interested, "link" would be a URL to the publication online somewhere (if it existed), "status" is a 1/0 value that lets the faculty member "hide" a publication from their list, and "position" is a jQuery sortable feature that lets them arrange their publication list however they want (versus by "id" or the title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it doesn't look like you need to group by anything.  You can create an array of publications based on year in php by going through the MySQL results.  Not tested one bit, but I hope you get that idea.  You can do this within the query parsing like Marc B shows as well...which may be better depending on the number of publications we're talking about.

```
$publications = array();
$q = mysql_query("SELECT `bibliography`,`year`,`link`,`position` FROM `faculty_pubs` WHERE `faculty_id`='$faculty_id' AND `status`=1 ORDER BY `year` DESC, `position` ASC");
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
 // separate publication out by year
 $publications[$r['year']][] = $r;
}

// no need to sort the array since all the results were put in order by the SQL sorting
foreach($publications as $year => $pub) {
 echo '<p>'.$year.'</p>';
 echo '<ul>';
 foreach($pub as $p) {
  echo '<li><a href="'.$p['link'].'">Publication title or position here</a></li>';
 }
 echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: thanks, Aaron. PS - I would use a do/while loop instead of just while(), because the latter tends to skip row 0.

Comment: Stephan - I've never had a while() skip row zero, ever.  A do/while could work, but you're doing extra work to make sure a value is present on the first iteration.  A while() makes sure something is there and doesn't skip rows.

Comment: hmm, I've read about that problem on various websites, but suppose maybe that was the issue (there wasn't a value in the first iteration). Either way, thank you again for the help, I needed to see it for it to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you're storing that in a single flat table, then displaying them by year is a purely "display" problem. Your query would spit out results looking like:

```
| bibliography | year | link       | position |
-----------------------------------------------
| blah blah    | 2008 | http://... | ???      |
| blah blah    | 2009 | http://... | ???      |
| blah blah    | 2009 | http://... | ???      |
| blah blah    | 2010 | http://... | ???      |
etc...
```

You'd simply loop over the results, keep track of the year, and whenever a new year record shows up, do whatever formatting you need (new <ul>, new table, whatever...).

```
$previous_year = null;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
     if ($previous_year != $row['year']) {
         // start a new year
     }
     ... display publication
     $previous_year = $row['year']
}
```

Comment: Thank yo! for this particular web page, I suppose you're right about it being something I could manipulate on the display side easily enough. But it would be very helpful to know how to approach this in a way that could take my data set and reorganize it into these groups.

Comment: SQL is for retrieving data, not formatting it.  Right problem in the right layer.